# ROR postgres upsert hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, upsert

I am trying to upsert this row:

schema.db

```
t.text "address_field"
```

address.rb

```
serialize :address_field, Hash
```

migration file

```
enable_extension 'hstore' unless extension_enabled?('hstore')

values = []
Address.find_each do |address|
    new_address_field = {first_line => "Street", second_line => "City" }
    values << [{id: address.id}, {address_field: new_address_field}]
end

Upsert.batch(Address.connection, Address.table_name) do |upsert|
  values.each do |p|
    upsert.row(p[0], p[1])
  end
end
```

The error that I receive is:

```
nameError: uninitialized constant PgHstore
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with upsert and postgresql. 
their team is working on something for it but as far as I read no fix news yet.

https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert/issues/60

you can try to migrate your data to an other database.